# How Can I Use a Java Application Instead of Desktop?

Tags: java, ubuntu, system, desktop

I want to make a Java Application that will start automatically when I start the computer and will run instead of the desktop, so the desktop-terminal etc will be unreachable for users. The users must use nothing but the application and when they close the application, the computer also must be turned off automatically. How can I do such a thing for a simple Java Application (jar)?

Comment: In which OS you need this?

Comment: @Frighi I want to make this in Ubuntu

Comment: I guess a good configuration of the window manager would allow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, for ubuntu you have to:

- Remove desktop environment, just look around for some guides, it depends by which desktop you have (GNOME, XFCE, KDE, etc). https://askubuntu.com/a/147870
- Add a script in /etc/rc.d and link it in rcS.d https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83752.
  The script have to run your application, wait for end and shutdown,
  an example could be:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  nohup java -jar MyApp.jar &
  wait
  /sbin/shutdown -r now
  ```

**Try this in a virtual machine that you can reach in SSH or in some other ways, after you removed desktop environment, you cannot open a terminal.**